# How to read JSON from external domain with javascript

Tags: json, jsonp, getjson, stringify

I'm new to javascript.
I have a working code that reads a JSON file locally, now the JSON moved to another domain and I can't manage to read it. I saw all the questions on JSONP but was unsuccessful to make it work.

The original code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index_files/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   
</head>
<body class="UI">
<h1 id="number"></h1>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

$.getJSON('data.json', function(data)
{
 var views=data.mysite.today; 
 document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = formatNumber(views);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The JSON file (data.json) looks like this:

```html
{
     "mysite":
     {
         "today": 1000,
         "week": 7000,
         "month": 30000
     },
  "another_site":
     {
         "today": 100,
         "week": 700,
         "month": 3000 
     }
     
 }
```

Lets say the data.json is located on: http://www.example.com/data.json

Tried this but it obviously didn't work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index_files/style.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   
</head>
<body class="UI">
<h1 id="number"></h1>

<script  type = "text/javascript">
a = function(data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    var obj=JSON.parse(data);
    var views =obj.mysite.today;
     document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = formatNumber(views);
    };
</script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://www.example.com/data.json"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you read about jsonp so you know that's the correct way to do it... yet you're not using it...

Comment: also, if it's on another server you're not going to find it at "data.json"... i feel like you're not even trying.'

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not helpful debugging information. again, you know jsonp is the correct way, so try that, then post the code and tell us **What** didn't work about it.

Comment: also, there is an edit link under your question. please edit the question and add the code there, don't put it in the comments.

Comment: I tried but since I'm new to javascript I didn't succeed to make it work - edited the post with my attempt code.

Comment: what didn't work.. you get an error, anything appear in the console? be specific...

Comment: i gave you the answer but for future reference you need to actually try before posting on here, and when you do post here you need to be real specific. you could have honestly figured this out yourself if you bothered to do a google search. would have taken you 3 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can use JSONP like so to get stuff off remote servers..

```
$.ajax({
    url: "full url to remote page goes here",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks great, Can you please provide me with a full working code using this method, I don't understand exactly how to implement it on my code - where is the variable that collects the data from JSON, where to put the rest of the code etc.

Comment: Trust me, I'm not - been working on this for 4 hours, I'm very new to Javascript - started yesterday.

Comment: then maybe you need to read some basic js tutorials. i can't be anymore specific than i already have been without writing your code for you, and we don't write code for people at S.O., and we're not here to teach you javascript. best of luck to you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this from what I understood from your example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index_files/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   
</head>
<body class="UI">
<h1 id="number"></h1>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>


$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com/data.json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function( response ) {
  var views=response.today; 
   document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = formatNumber(views);
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing appears on screen, error on console is:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :